# How in angular to set an input field focused using name, model or id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form and want when cursor leaves field one(blur), it will check if data is the word "test". And if the data doesn't contain, it will go back ad make field 1 focused again.

```
<form name='yourForm' novalidate ng-submit="save(yourForm)">

        <label>Field 1</label>
        <input type="email" name="first" ng-model="fname" ng-blur="displayData(fname)">
        <br><br>

        <label>Field 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="last" ng-model="lname" ng-blur="displayData(lname)">

        <button type="button">finish</button>
</form>
```

So I cannot find a solution how to set the field focus using field name, id or maybe ng-model.

I want to do something like this but in angular:

```
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1];
inp.focus();
```

but don't know how to get input index or to get input name.

Comment: Could you add an id to the input tag and do: document.getElementById(idName).focus();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a directive like this:

#### UPDATED

Added a string to the attribute value to determine what the input should contain as a value before blurring

https://jsfiddle.net/0bcsvLk5/

#### Angular

```
function inputBlur() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      inputBlur:'@'
    },
    link: link
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attr) {
    element.on('blur', function() {
      if (element.val() != scope.inputBlur) {
        element[0].focus();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fname" input-blur="test" class="form-control">
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="lname" class="form-control">
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="email" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the function displayData() in your $scope, and to get the element value you could use document.getElementByName('name')[0].value

See working demo: http://jsbin.com/xeyozocoyi/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.displayData = function(){

   var inp = document.getElementsByName('first')[0];

    if(inp.value != "test"){
       alert("Will focus because value is" + inp.value);
      inp.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

});
```

and your view

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" >   
    <form name='yourForm' novalidate ng-submit="save(yourForm)">

        <label>Field 1</label>
        <input type="email" name="first" ng-model="fname"   ng-blur="displayData()">
        <br><br>

        <label>Field 2</label>
        <input type="text"   name="last" ng-model="lname"  ng-blur="displayData()">

        <button type="button">finish</button>
</form>
</div>
```